Error Using NCClient While Connecting to Cisco NXOS Sandbox
I'm currently new at this thing, and doesn't have much references. So i don't know how to properly ask this
I'm currently trying to get NCClient to work with NXOS Sandbox from Cisco. My goal is just to print some interfaces information.
Using this code:
from ncclient import manager
from pprint import pprint
import xmltodict

router = {"ip": "sbx-nxos-mgmt.cisco.com",
          "port": 830,
          "user": "admin",
          "pass": "*",
          "device_params": {"name": "nexus"}
          }

netconf_filter = """
<interfaces xmlns="http://openconfig.net/yang/interfaces">
  <interface>
      <name>Ethernet1/1</name>
  </interface>
</interfaces>
"""

m = manager.connect(host=router["ip"],
                    port=router["port"],
                    username=router["user"],
                    password=router["pass"],
                    hostkey_verify=False)

interface_netconf = m.get_config("running", filter=("subtree", netconf_filter))
interface_python = xmltodict.parse(interface_netconf.xml)["rpc-reply"]["data"]
pprint(interface_python["interfaces"]["interface"]["name"]["#text"])

But i always get this error:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RPCError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-3cd27fa48f42> in <cell line: 26>()
     24                     hostkey_verify=False)
     25 
---> 26 interface_netconf = m.get_config("running", filter=("subtree", netconf_filter))
     27 interface_python = xmltodict.parse(interface_netconf.xml)["rpc-reply"]["data"]
     28 pprint(interface_python["interfaces"]["interface"]["name"]["#text"])

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ncclient/manager.py in execute(self, cls, *args, **kwds)
    255 
    256     def execute(self, cls, *args, **kwds):
--> 257         return cls(self._session,
    258                    device_handler=self._device_handler,
    259                    async_mode=self._async_mode,

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ncclient/operations/retrieve.py in request(self, source, filter, with_defaults)
    164                 self._session.server_capabilities,
    165             )
--> 166         return self._request(node)
    167 
    168 class GetSchema(RPC):

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ncclient/operations/rpc.py in _request(self, op)
    371                         errors = self._reply.errors
    372                         if len(errors) > 1:
--> 373                             raise RPCError(to_ele(self._reply._raw), errs=errors)
    374                         else:
    375                             raise self._reply.error

RPCError: error: /top:System/top:intf-items/top:svi-items/top:If-list Device-model namespace not loaded
error: /top:System/top:intf-items/top:svi-items/top:If-list Device-model namespace not loaded

Tried switching different NS for the filter, but still no luck.
Also, i got the base code from here
And i also used Google Colab as my workspace.
